# Idiom to describe possibility of effect

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, idioms

Sometimes I need to write a function that may or may not have an effect.

Is there a functional (or otherwise) idiom to describe this state of affairs? The prefix `maybe` describes it, but is there something idiomatic?

For example:

```
function maybe(guardCb) {
  return function(cb) {
    return function() {
      if(guardCb.apply(this, arguments)) {
        return cb.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    }
  };
}

function isFoo(args) {
  return args.isFoo();
}

function doSomething(args) {
  return foo.bar(args.bam);
}

maybe(isFoo)(doSomething)(args);
```

I am aware of the maybe monad, but it seems different to this.

Comment: As of me, I will write the condition of `doSomething()` getting invoked into the function name.

Comment: Are you looking for naming conventions or a programming technique?

Comment: Programming technique I suppose. I am interested in implementing a conditional in a "functional" style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a pure function. The equivalent Haskell code is:

```hs
maybe :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> b) -> a -> Maybe b
maybe p f x = if p x then Just (f x) else Nothing

example = maybe p f x
```

There's no special name for this function. However, it can be simplified:

```hs
maybe :: Bool -> b -> Maybe b
maybe b y = if b then Just y else Nothing

example = (maybe <$> p <*> f) x
```

Notice that `p :: a -> Bool`, `f :: a -> b` and `maybe p f :: a -> Maybe b` all have one thing in common (i.e. `((->) a)`). This is the [`Reader`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#reader) interface and it can be abstracted out using the [`Applicative`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors) type class, which is what I did.

However, this is not good code. A better abstraction would be:

```hs
maybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> Maybe c
maybe p f = fmap f . p
```

Notice that `p :: a -> Maybe b` is now a [Kleisli arrow](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/06/monads-kleisli-arrows-comonads-and.html) instead of a simple predicate function. We have moved the conditional logic out of the `maybe` function. In JavaScript your code would now be:

```js
isFoo(args).map(doSomething);
```

All you need to do is define a `Maybe` data type and implement its `Functor` interface:

```js
function Maybe(constructor) {
    this.constructor = constructor || this;
}

var Nothing = new Maybe;

function Just(value) {
    var maybe = new Maybe(Just);
    maybe.value = value;
    return maybe;
}

Maybe.prototype.map = function (functor) {
    switch (this.constructor) {
    case Nothing: return Nothing;
    case Just:    return Just(functor(this.value));
    }
};
```

Of course, you would also need to redefine `isFoo` as follows:

```js
function isFoo(args) {
    return args.isFoo() ? Just(args) : Nothing;
}
```

The `doSomthing` function can remain as is. Hope that helps.

The idiom that you are looking for is a `Functor` interface.

Comment: What is the name for this field of expertise? Language theory? Did you learn this from Haskell or academically?

Comment: It's [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory), a branch of mathematics. Category theory generalizes mathematics. However, it's useful in programming as well (for generalizing various common interfaces like `Functor` and `Monad`). Therefore, it's used extensively in Haskell and you learn a lot of category theory when you learn Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word "possible" is appropriate to hint about the effect of the function.

```
correctPossibleError()

handlePossibleNameChange()

erasePossibleOuterCircle() 

includePossibleMatches()
```